# Replacing spacing in http request with "+" character

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, http, google-geocoding-api

I am doing a project in which i have to geocode addresses on the data base and then return the results to a separate table.

I have a request like this

```
@foreach(var row in data){ 
    https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="@row.ADDRESS1+@row.CITY+@row.ST+@row.ZIP+@row.COUNTRY"&key=apikey
}
```

which will turn into something like this

> https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address="111 bill street+jacob town+AB+X1X 1X1+CA"&key=apikey

I was wondering if there is an easy way to replace the spaces that you see in the address parameter into a "+" character.

Comment: `string.Replace(" ", "+");`?

Comment: Use `@Uri.EscapeDataString(row.ADDRESS1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find my answer. I used:

```
@HttpUtility.UrlEncode(row.ADDRESS1)
```

This replaced the spaces with a `+` character.